# Bevelled Edge Shading

Tags: modeling, mesh

Running into some trouble creating a bevel to break up some hard edges on a model I'm working on. In particular, I'm running into issues anywhere that I have a hole cut in the model (windows, landing gear bays, etc).

[image: No Bevel]

For example, here's the opening for the forward landing gear bay without the bevel. Shading is nice and smooth.

[image: No Bevel with Mesh]

Here's the same image showing the mesh. Ignore the red line, that's located inside the bay and not part of the topology I'm trying to work with.

[image: Beveled]

Now, here's the same section beveled. The bevel is a single segment and 1 mm. As you can see, it completely screws up the shading at the corners. I can fix it with an Edge Split modifier, but that just creates another hard edge, so pretty much defeats the purpose of beveling it in the first place.

I have this problem everywhere there's detailing that cuts a hole into the surface of the model.

Comment: Could you reupload that second image except without the hidden faces option enabled? It's extremely hard to tell what's going on.

Comment: Could you upload a .blend file?

Comment: Blend file added. The edges marked as sharp is everywhere I intend to put a 1mm, 1-segment bevel. The ideal situation would be to eliminate the Edge Split modifier entirely and just use the bevels for the same effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I ended up putting an extra edge loop around outside the bevel. While that didn't ELIMINATE the shading, it minimized it enough so as to be no longer visible.